# Debconf error in system with systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, debconf

I've encountered the following problem when using `debconf` to configure a package in Ubuntu 16.04 during installation.

More precisely, the package uses `debconf` to save configurations files, and right after, in the `postinst` script, a service is started. This service also uses a `debconf` module to load the configurations saved in the previous step.

However, the service started with `systemd` fails with the error:

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

From what I could find, `dpkg` is still accessing this file with the `debconf` frontend, and the service crashes when it tries to start another frontend (the environmental variable `DEBIAN_HAS_FRONTEND` is not passed to the service). I have tried forcing the env variable `DEBIAN_HAS_FRONTEND` in the script, but then other errors appear.

I think I should force starting the daemon after the `dpkg` process has ended, and `debconf` has already finished, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found the problem, I'll post it in case it is helpful for somebody in the future.

As I said, I was trying to start a service from the `postinst` script, and said service was trying to use `debconfig` to fetch some configuration parameters, but there was an error with `debconf` since there was already once instance running (although all the configuration was done in the `config` file, and not in `postinst`).

The problem, was then, that there was an active `debconf` frontend during the execution of the `postinst` script, while I was not using `debconf`. I had , however, commented the line that loads the `confmodue`:

```
# . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
```

Apparently, [`dpkg-reconfigure`](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure) (and I guess `dpkg` too) consider that `confmodule` is loaded if they match the "confmodule" string on the files (`config`, `postinst` and `prerm`). So, while I wasn't effectively loading confmodule, dpkg-reconfigure wasn't releasing the frontend, and that's why the service couldn't initiate another `debconf` instance. The solution was to simply delete that line.

Answer (score 1):

To start off, using debconf in a standalone program feels wrong. To quote `man debconf-devel`, section OTHER SCRIPTS:

> You  can  also  use debconf in other, standalone programs. The issue to watch out for here is
>          that debconf is not intended to be, and must not be used as a registry. This  is  unix  after
>          all,  and  programs  are  configured  by files in /etc, not by some nebulous debconf database
>          (that is only a cache anyway and might get blown away). So think long and hard  before  using
>          debconf in a standalone program.

The same manual page also helps with your actual problem in the previous section (THE POSTINST SCRIPT):

> If your postinst launches a daemon, make sure you tell debconf to  STOP  at  the  end,
>                 since debconf can become a little confused about when your postinst is done otherwise.

That is, issue `db_stop` before launching your daemon (even if it does not use debconf itself).

Comment: Would you suggest using another program to configure mine? As for the db_stop, I've tried running db_stop before launching my daemon, but with no success, debconf does not stop immediately.

Comment: You should configure your program with debconf in the config and the postinst scripts of the package. Don't use debconf in your program.

Comment: That's what I do, except I read the configurations from my program, so I have to load the confmodule. I don't make any modifications. And another issue: if I don't load confmodule in the ponstinst script, I cannot configure my program during installation, but I can if I do dpkg-reconfigure. Maybe dpkg -i does not run the config script?

Comment: Ask questions in your config script, save the answers into config files in your postinst, and don't use debconf in your program: use the config files written by your postinst. Yes, dpkg runs the config script through the postinst, that's one of the reasons why it must include the confmodule. Please read `man debconf-devel`, down to the HACKS section.